# direct database query with select_all using place holders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make a query with select_all, something like this:

```
query << "SELECT blah blah FROM blah blah WHERE status_id IN(?, ?)"
query << " AND end_date IS NULL "
...
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query.join, STATUS_1, STATUS_2)
```

This of course does not work.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a specific model? Or you just want to build a query?

Comment: It is a general query that I build, not related to a model. That is the reason that I don't use rails magics

Answer (score 0):

As the ActiveRecord is used you could go with Arel alone, as it is still a dependancy for ActiveRecord:

```
table = Arel::Table.new("your_table")
select = [:id, :name]
statuses = %w[active new]
end_date = nil
> puts table.project(*select).
   where(table[:status].in(statuses)).
   where(table[:end_date].eq(end_date)).to_sql
```

Produces query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM "your_table" WHERE "your_table"."status" IN ('active', 'new') AND "your_table"."end_date" IS NULL
```